# What is the purpose for the + prefix in excel, in-cell formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have inherited a spreadsheet project that is full of cell references with a preceding "+". What does this mean?

Example:
"=+Sheet2!A3"

Also, when I click inside the formula bar the name area on the left says "OFFSET". Does this have anything to do with the "+"?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  See [the StackOverflow faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @Justin, questions about the evaluation of expressions, even simple ones, qualify in my opinion. I just looked on meta to see what other opinions were out there and wound up writing this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on/76767#76767

Comment: @jtolle - Fair enough; that's a good point.  Although this turned out to be more of a Lotus 1-2-3 vs. Excel software quirk, the OP didn't know that at the outset.  I still think this question and answers would be somewhat better suited for superuser.com, but I'm not strongly opposed to it here.

Comment: @Justin, I didn't know about that either, and I would have thought that e.g. =+TRUE would evaluate to the number 1 and not the boolean TRUE. So thanks for asking, @Theo! (But you accepted the wrong answer I think.)

Comment: @Justin, I hadn't heard of superuser before. Thanks for the info.  @jtolle, yeah I thought it was cool that it would do that. But then I checked it, and it didn't. So I changed the answer. I will be more careful next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preceding `+` doesn't really do anything.  It is like how `+2` and `2` are the same number, as are `+(-x)` and `(-x)`.

The real question is *why* they all start with a `+`.  Best would be to ask the original author.  Note that there are 3 symbols that you can type to start a formula, `=`, `-`, and `+`.  Using either `+` or `-`, Excel will automatically add an `=` sign at the beginning after you are done entering the formula.  My guesses are:

- He used to have another term added before the `+`, but didn't need it anymore and did a find-and-replace operation to get rid of it.
- He didn't know that you could type `=` to start a formula.
- He used some strange keyboard or numpad with the `+` key more easily accessible than `=`.

The `OFFSET` name on the cell doesn't have anything to do with this; it is just a named range.

Comment: Just tracked down the old developer. He was used to using Lotus 1-2-3, where you put the "+" instead of the "=" for a formula!

Comment: I see a lot of people in my office start typing their formulas with "+" instead of "=". It must be learned behavior from some other system like that.

Answer (score 1):

The "+" has no purpose.  A "-" in that spot would negate the value in the referenced cell, but a "+" is redundant as it is exactly the same as using "=Sheet2!A3"

Answer (score 0):

That offset can mean that the value exceeds the max or min limit (e.g Excel uses 32-bit fields to store numbers) or it refer to a cell that doesn't exist (maybe you try to refer a column after AMJ or a row after 65535). More generally "Offset" usually refer to a value that is out of the range of acceptable values.

Comment: Using `+` to convert to a number doesn't work for me in Excel 2003 and 2007 -- cell B1 displays `TRUE`, not `1`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I don't know why it worked when I tried last time... Anyway he's already solved.

Comment: @Theo Love - I'm not sure why you accepted this answer. If it's the info about "Offset" I'd like to see a link for it, or an example of how to generate it; I've never heard of "Offset" showing in this case, and it's hard to search for it since all of the results are about the `OFFSET()` function.

Comment: Yeah, my error. i didn't realize I had left this answer checked. Regarding the "Offset", I was just used to seeing the named ranges appearing there. I guess now in Excel 2007, and Excel Mac 2011, whenever you put an "=" and put your cursor in the formula bar it brings up a list of the most recently used functions there instead.